# "import plotly.graph_objects as go" in Streamlit

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I'm currently trying to code a program for a computer science project in Streamlit.

I want to `import plotly.graph_objs as go` to visualise an output, but no matter what I do, I get the error `name 'go' is not defined`.

What am I doing wrong?

That are the current libraries i want to import

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import joblib
import folium
from streamlit_folium import folium_static
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import re
import plotly.graph_objs as go
```

Comment: what's the full error message?

Comment: This is probably because you are importing an old graph object. Replace this with. `import plotly.graph_objects as go`